# Zermelo-Fraenkel Set Theory Question regarding Ordered Pairs

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Problem:
Show that $\{x,\{y\}\}$ is not suitable as a definition of the ordered pair $(x,y)$, because it does not have the ordered pair property: For any sets $x,y,u,v$ if $( x,y ) = ( u,v )$, then $x=u$ and $y=v$.

To do this problem, do I have to find two pairs of sets, say $(x,y)$ and $(z,w)$, such that ordered pair $(x,y)$ = ordered pair $(z,w)$ but $(x,y)\neq(z,w)$?

I appreciate any support that can be given to me. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure if this is the right way of showing this, but have you tried showing that you can show $x=w$ and $y=z$ instead of $x=z$ and $y=w$ with that definition for $x\neq y$?

Comment: You need to find $x,y,u,v$ such that the "fake" ordered pairs $\{x,\{y\}\}$ and $\{u,\{v\}\}$ are equal but at least one of the two equations $x=u$ and $y=v$ is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that $(x,y)=(z,w)$. This means that $\{x,\{y\}\}=\{z,\{w\}\}$. We have that $z=x$ or $z=\{y\}$ and that $\{w\}=x$ or $\{w\}=\{y\}$ (which implies $w=y$). We want $x\neq z$ or $y\neq w$. Let's choose $x=\{\varnothing\}$, $z=\{\{\varnothing\}\}$, $y=\{\varnothing\}$, and $w=\varnothing$.

That works even more than we needed.

Comment: I'm using the OPs definition of a proposed ordered pair.